# How to connect google contact using google api in python

Tags: python

I want to connect my contact using python so i can add that program in my AI model which help me to message them using what'sapp.

I had used file handling to open a excel file that contain my contact and using loop i access them and add it my program.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to automate sending messages to your contacts using WhatsApp in Python, you can use a library like selenium to control a web browser. Note that automating WhatsApp in this way might violate WhatsApp's terms of service, and you should be aware of the legal and ethical implications.

Here's an example using selenium to automate sending messages via WhatsApp. Make sure to install the necessary libraries:

```bash
pip install selenium webdriver_manager
```

so the code is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Function to send a WhatsApp message
def send_whatsapp_message(contact_name, message):
    # Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    
    # Open WhatsApp Web
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
    
    input("Scan the QR code on the browser, then press Enter to continue...")
    
    try:
        # Locate the search box
        search_box = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[contains(@class, 'copyable-text')][@contenteditable='true']")
        
        # Type the contact name
        search_box.send_keys(contact_name)
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the contact to load
        
        # Select the contact
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        
        # Locate the message input box
        message_box = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@contenteditable='true'][@data-tab='1']")
        
        # Type and send the message
        message_box.send_keys(message)
        message_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        
        print(f"Message sent to {contact_name} successfully!")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
    
    finally:
        # Close the browser window
        driver.quit()
```

## Example usage

```py
contact_name = "John Doe"
message = "Hello, this is a test message from my Python script!"
send_whatsapp_message(contact_name, message)
```